# Why is CLLocation not serialised?

Tags: json, swift, serialization, handyjson

I have the following code. `Place` is serialised if and only if it inherits from `HandyJSON`, but the `latLong` property is not serialised.

Why is `HandyJSON` ignoring this property? I tried making `Place` a class instead of a struct but it didn't change the outcome.

```
import CoreLocation
import HandyJSON

struct Place {

    var latLong : CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 51.5256, longitude: -0.0875)
}

extension Place : HandyJSON {}

extension CLLocation : HandyJSON {}

extension CLLocationCoordinate2D : HandyJSON {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up and created my own simple custom type. This will at least make my code more generic.

```
import HandyJSON

struct LatLong : HandyJSON {

    public init() {

        self.latitude = 51.5256
        self.longitude = -0.0875
    }

    public init(latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {

        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
    }

    var latitude: Double
    var longitude: Double
}
```